# How am I getting a DoubleRenderError?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I keep getting the DoubleRenderError and while I understand that Ruby has DoubleRenderError rule, my understanding is that it does not imply that we cannot have more than one "render" statement in an action. Just that in the execution flow of code, "render" should not be met more than once, yet that is not happening in my code. Can anybody help? Here is the code:

```
class RegistrationsController < Milia::RegistrationsController

  skip_before_action :authenticate_tenant!, :only => [:new, :create, :cancel]

  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # TODO: options if non-standard path for new signups view
  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # create -- intercept the POST create action upon new sign-up
  # new tenant account is vetted, then created, then proceed with devise create user
  # CALLBACK: Tenant.create_new_tenant  -- prior to completing user account
  # CALLBACK: Tenant.tenant_signup      -- after completing user account
  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def create
    # have a working copy of the params in case Tenant callbacks
      # make any changes
    tenant_params = sign_up_params_tenant
    user_params   = sign_up_params_user
    coupon_params = sign_up_params_coupon

    sign_out_session!
       # next two lines prep signup view parameters
    prep_signup_view( tenant_params, user_params, coupon_params )

       # validate recaptcha first unless not enabled
    if !::Milia.use_recaptcha  ||  verify_recaptcha

      Tenant.transaction  do
        @tenant = Tenant.create_new_tenant( tenant_params, user_params, coupon_params)
        if @tenant.errors.empty?   # tenant created
          if @tenant.plan == 'premium'
            @payment = Payment.new({ email: user_params["email"],
              token: params[:payment]["token"],
              tenant: @tenant })
            flash[:error] = "Please check registration errors" unless @payment.valid?

            begin
              @payment.process_payment
              @payment.save
            rescue Exception => e
              flash[:error] = e.message
              @tenant.destroy
              log_action("Payment failed")
              render :new and return
            end
          end
        else
          resource.valid?
          log_action( "tenant create failed", @tenant )
          render :new
        end # if .. then .. else no tenant errors

        if flash[:error].blank? || flash[:error].empty? #payment successful
          initiate_tenant( @tenant )    # first time stuff for new tenant

          devise_create( user_params )   # devise resource(user) creation; sets resource

          if resource.errors.empty?   #  SUCCESS!

            log_action( "signup user/tenant success", resource )
              # do any needed tenant initial setup
            Tenant.tenant_signup(resource, @tenant, coupon_params)

          else  # user creation failed; force tenant rollback
            log_action( "signup user create failed", resource )
            raise ActiveRecord::Rollback   # force the tenant transaction to be rolled back
          end  # if..then..else for valid user creation
        else
          resource.valid?
          log_action("Payment processing failed", @tenant )
          render :new and return
        end # if.. then .. else no tenant errors
      end  #  wrap tenant/user creation in a transaction
    else
      flash[:error] = "Recaptcha codes didn't match; please try again"
         # all validation errors are passed when the sign_up form is re-rendered
      resource.valid?
      @tenant.valid?
      log_action( "recaptcha failed", resource )
      render :new
    end
  end   # def create

  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  protected
  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) + ::Milia.whitelist_user_params
  end

  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def sign_up_params_tenant()
      params.require(:tenant).permit( ::Milia.whitelist_tenant_params )
    end

  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def sign_up_params_user()
      params.require(:user).permit( ::Milia.whitelist_user_params )
    end

  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # sign_up_params_coupon -- permit coupon parameter if used; else params
  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def sign_up_params_coupon()
      ( ::Milia.use_coupon ?
        params.require(:coupon).permit( ::Milia.whitelist_coupon_params )  :
        params
      )
    end

  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # sign_out_session! -- force the devise session signout
  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def sign_out_session!()
      Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name) if user_signed_in?
    end

  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # devise_create -- duplicate of Devise::RegistrationsController
    # same as in devise gem EXCEPT need to prep signup form variables
  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def devise_create( user_params )

      build_resource(user_params)

        # if we're using milia's invite_member helpers
      if ::Milia.use_invite_member
          # then flag for our confirmable that we won't need to set up a password
        resource.skip_confirm_change_password  = true
      end

      if resource.save
        yield resource if block_given?
        log_action( "devise: signup user success", resource )
        if resource.active_for_authentication?
          set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
          sign_up(resource_name, resource)
          respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
        else
          set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
          expire_data_after_sign_in!
          respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
        end
      else
        clean_up_passwords resource
        log_action( "devise: signup user failure", resource )
        prep_signup_view(  @tenant, resource, params[:coupon] )
        respond_with resource
      end
    end

  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    headers['refresh'] = "0;url=#{root_path}"
    root_path
  end

  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    headers['refresh'] = "0;url=#{root_path}"
    root_path
  end
  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  def log_action( action, resource=nil )
    err_msg = ( resource.nil? ? '' : resource.errors.full_messages.uniq.join(", ") )
    logger.debug(
      "MILIA >>>>> [register user/org] #{action} - #{err_msg}"
    ) unless logger.nil?
  end

  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

end   # class Registrations
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is kinda complex, I think I can't go through and see what happened. My idea, you can easily catch the bug by adding some extra code like this:

```
def custom_render(params)
 byebug # Put breakpoint here
 render params
end
```

Then replace all render in your function with `custom_render`, examine with breakpoints, and you will see what happens.

Comment: Hieu, I will give that a try. I do want to share that i started commenting different parts of the render code on different lines and well look for yourself, what finally made it work, which I still don't get it:             
      else
        resource.valid?
        log_action( "tenant create failed", @tenant )
#         render :new
      end # if .. then .. else no tenant errors